# How can I write this record search in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, models

```
 #find the most recent news item for a specific locale
  def self.find_most_recent_news_for_locale

    first(:include => :news_item_detail,:conditions => ["news_items.created_at= ? AND  news_item_details.locale = ?",  maximum(:created_at), I18n.locale])
  end
```

The Models

```
class NewsItem < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :news_item_detail

end

class NewsItemDetail < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :news_item

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3, you should use the `where` method for creating conditions:

```
def self.find_most_recent_news_for_locale
  where("news_items.created_at = ? AND news_item_details.locale = ?",
    maximum(:created_at), 
    I18n.locale).includes(:news_item_details).first
end
```

You might want to watch [episode #202](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3) of Railscasts as a quick tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Behrang, I did watch that episode but was having trouble getting the syntax. Now you pointed me in the right direction :)